# How to turn Raspberry Pi into Wi-Fi router?

Tags: wifi, internet

To turn Raspberry Pi into a Wi-Fi router capable of serving internet to multiple clients:

1. What hardware do I need?
2. What software components one shall create to run it?

Comment: You don't need OpenWRT; Raspbian has a [hostapd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostapd) package (the Jouni Malinen implementation).  You just need to find a decent adapter with this capability and a known working linux driver; perhaps a +/2 model will be better because of the USB power draw.

Comment: I've used an A+ with Edimax nano adapters as a router with no problems. Keep in mind, you're not going to get very good performance with the RPi as a wi-fi to wi-fi router compared to dedicated hardware. It works reasonably well for wired-wifi routing.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. However, the answer to "*is it practical?*" would depend on your definition of *multiple*.

You need to have a Wi-Fi USB card which has allows/provides [AP mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point). Once you have it attached then you can install and configure `hostapd` and I am certain that someone must have documented the configuration process online in detail. This may involve `iptables` modification/entries as well.

Feel free to comment in case of query/doubt. I have worked on a project (which was for traffic monitoring) in which my client had the setup done and I would send him the cross-compiled binaries. Therefore, I am certain that this can be done but again, the practicality of the solution would depend on many factors.